# Find the printer makers also producing PCs with the lowest RAM capacity and the highest processor speed of all PCs having the lowest RAM capacity

Tags: sql

Exercise: 25 (Serge I: 2003-02-14)

Find the printer makers also producing PCs with the lowest RAM capacity and the highest processor speed of all PCs having the lowest RAM capacity.

```
*The database scheme consists of four tables:
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)*
```

And this's my query like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.maker)
FROM product p
INNER JOIN pc
ON pc.MODEL    = p.MODEL
WHERE pc.speed =
  ( SELECT MAX(speed) speed FROM pc WHERE ram =
    (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc
    )
  )
AND p.TYPE   = 'PC'
AND p.maker IN
  (SELECT maker FROM product WHERE TYPE = 'Printer'
  );
enter code here
```

Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database
Please tell me where I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sub Query

```
select distinct p.maker from product p where type = 'Printer'
 AND maker IN (
    select maker from product p,pc where p.model = pc.model 
 AND 
    pc.ram IN (select min(ram) from pc) 
 AND
    pc.speed IN (select max(speed) from pc where ram IN (select min(ram) from pc)) 
              )
```

## INTERSECT

```
select
    distinct p.maker
from
    product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN pc
ON p.model = pc.model
WHERE 
    maker IN (select maker from product p where type = 'Printer'
          INTERSECT
          select maker from product p where type = 'PC'
        )
AND
    pc.ram IN (select min(ram) from pc)
AND
    pc.speed IN (select max(speed) from pc where ram IN (select min(ram) from pc))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found where's wrong here

```
pc.speed =
  ( SELECT MAX(speed) speed FROM pc WHERE ram =
    (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc
    )
  )
```

It must be

```
pc.ram   =
    (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc
    )
  AND pc.speed =
    (SELECT MAX(speed) FROM pc WHERE ram =
      (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc
      )
    )
```